# How to call chart-zoom resetZoom function when char data changes?

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I have a Vue project with following packages installed.

├── chart.js@4.3.0
├── chartjs-plugin-zoom@2.0.1
├── vite@4.3.9
├── vue-chartjs@5.2.0
└── vue@3.3.4

I created a "LineChart.vue" components, what I want is that when the "chartData" was changed in parement, I want to call the "resetZoom" function provided in "chartjs-plugin-zoom" package.

How can I do this in vue-chartjs 5.2? it seems that since v4 version, the vue-chartjs have data change watcher and options change watcher by default. Wrapper will update or re-render the chart if new data or new options is passed. but how to hook the data change event in my component?

Contents of "LineChart.vue"

```
<template>
  <Line :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions"/> 
</template>
  
<script>
import zoom from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom';

import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  Filler
} from 'chart.js'
import { Chart, Line} from 'vue-chartjs'
import { watch, ref, reactive} from 'vue';
ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  Filler,
  zoom
)

export default {
  name: 'LineChart',
  components: { Line },
  props: ['chartData', 'chartOptions'],
  setup(props) {
    console.log("LineChart  setup!");
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried to add a watcher on chartData, but seems it doesn't work. I am a new in Vue, any one can help on this?

```
export default {
  name: 'LineChart',
  components: { Line },
  props: ['chartData', 'chartOptions'],
  setup(props) {
    watch( () => props.chartData, (newValue, oldValue) => {
      console.log("watcher triggled fro chartData", newValue, oldValue);
    },
    { deep: true }
    )
    console.log("LineChart  setup!");
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log("PmaGroupLineChart  mounted!");
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a [ref](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#access-to-chart-instance) in your chart to access it, and then call `resetZoom()` on that ref when data changes:

```
<Line :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions" ref="myLineChart"/>
```

```
setup() {
    const myLineChart = ref(null);
    
    watch(
        () => props.chartData,
        () => {
            myLineChart.resetZoom();
        },
        { deep: true }
    );

    return { myLineChart };
}
```

See [the Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) for more info on template refs.

Comment: Yitz's post is working for me after replacing the "this" to "getCurrentInstance()"

 setup(props) {
    const instance = getCurrentInstance()
    watch(
      () => props.chartData,
      () => {
          instance.refs.myLineChart.chart.resetZoom();
        }
    )
  }

Comment: Yeah sorry still got options syntax on my brain! `getCurrentInstance()` is not the recommended way though, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Agree, for the vue doc I could see that getCurrentInstance is only exposed for advanced use cases. 
In your answer, as the "myLineChart" is declared as a "ref", so we need to add ".value"  in javascript. just like this "myLineChart.value.chart.resetZoom();"
here is the working code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-jd6kac?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FLineChart.vue